# SharePoint 2013 and Kendo Grid cross domain call issues

Tags: kendo-ui, cross-domain, kendo-grid, sharepoint-2013

I am having a small issue that I just can't seem to figure out.  I am trying to make a simple SharePoint 2013 demo app that gets a few fields from a list on the parent site and binds to a kendo grid.

Due to the new nature of SP2013, app's get created in their own local site which makes these calls cross domain.  When I make the call, no data is pulled back.  When I compare a working call vs the call being made by the app, I can see that a cookie is not present in the call that is failing (which is why no data is being pulled back).  If anyone could offer any hints or suggestions on things to try, I would appreciate it.

The List I am trying to call is called KendoGridList and I am trying to pull back the first and last name and bind to the grid. Below is my code:

**EDIT: After looking into the code a little deeper, it looks like a cookie is not getting passed in the call to the service.  If I take the cookie from a normal rest call to the service which works and add it to the composer in fiddler the call goes through and returns data.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#grid").empty();

var siteUrl = "site url placed here";
var url = siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/Listdata.svc/KendoGridList/?$select=FirstName,LastName";
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        type: "odata",
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: url,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");
                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            type: "json",
            model: {
                fields: {
                    FirstName: "FirstName",
                    LastName: "LastName"
                }
            }
        },
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        change: function (e) { // data load completed for grid
        },
    },
    filterable: false,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    scrollable: false,
    //groupable: true,
    columns: [{
        field: "FirstName",
        title: "First Name",
        width: 50
    }, {
        field: "LastName",
        title: "Last Name",
        width: 50
    }
    ]
 });

});
```

I've also tried using:

```
read: {
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
      headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a provider-hosted app you should try using the SP cross-domain library.  I think your best bet is to retrieve the data using the library and then bind the resulting info to the grid.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx